# Removing shared characters in two character strings in R

Tags: r, character

I currently have two character strings (newIV and diffname) as follows:

```
> newIV
[1] "i1"  "i2"  "i3"  "i4"  "i5"  "i6"  "i7"  "i8"  "i9"  "i10"
[11] "i11" "i12" "i13" "i14" "i15" "i16" "i17" "i18" "i19" "i20"
[21] "i21" "i22" "i23" "i24" "i25" "i26" "i27" "i28" "i29" "i30"
[31] "i31" "i32" "i33" "i34" "i35" "i36" "i37" "i38" "i39" "i40"
[41] "i41" "i42" "i43" "i44" "i45" "i46" "i47" "i48" "i49" "i50"
[51] "i51" "i52" "i53" "i54" "i55" "i56" "i57" "i58" "i59" "i60"
[61] "i61" "i62" "i63" "i64" "i65" "i66" "i67" "i68" "i69" "i70"
[71] "i71" "i72" "i73" "i74" "i75" "i76" "i77" "i78" "i79" "i17"
[81] "i19" "i20" "i21" "i63" "i75"
```

and

```
> diffname
[1] "i17" "i19" "i20" "i21" "i63" "i75"
```

I want to automate the process so that newIV contains only the characters that are not found in diffname.  I have tried the following:

```
newIV<-newIV[-which(newIV==diffname)]
```

However, I continue to get an error when I try this.

```
Warning message:
In newIV == diffname :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `%in%`

```
 newIV[!newIV %in% diffname]
 #[1] "i1"  "i2"  "i3"  "i4"  "i5"  "i6"  "i7"  "i8"  "i9"  "i10" "i11" "i12"
 #[13] "i13" "i14" "i15" "i16" "i18" "i22" "i23" "i24" "i25" "i26" "i27" "i28"
 #[25] "i29" "i30" "i31" "i32" "i33" "i34" "i35" "i36" "i37" "i38" "i39" "i40"
 #[37] "i41" "i42" "i43" "i44" "i45" "i46" "i47" "i48" "i49" "i50" "i51" "i52"
 #[49] "i53" "i54" "i55" "i56" "i57" "i58" "i59" "i60" "i61" "i62" "i64" "i65"
 #[61] "i66" "i67" "i68" "i69" "i70" "i71" "i72" "i73" "i74" "i76" "i77" "i78"
#[73] "i79"
```

Or

```
 setdiff(newIV, diffname)
 #[1] "i1"  "i2"  "i3"  "i4"  "i5"  "i6"  "i7"  "i8"  "i9"  "i10" "i11" "i12"
 #[13] "i13" "i14" "i15" "i16" "i18" "i22" "i23" "i24" "i25" "i26" "i27" "i28"
 #[25] "i29" "i30" "i31" "i32" "i33" "i34" "i35" "i36" "i37" "i38" "i39" "i40"
 #[37] "i41" "i42" "i43" "i44" "i45" "i46" "i47" "i48" "i49" "i50" "i51" "i52"
 #[49] "i53" "i54" "i55" "i56" "i57" "i58" "i59" "i60" "i61" "i62" "i64" "i65"
 #[61] "i66" "i67" "i68" "i69" "i70" "i71" "i72" "i73" "i74" "i76" "i77" "i78"
 #[73] "i79"
```

Comment: @akrun  : I think it's good that you remind the OP's to accept the answer. I haven't been active here for long, but I find it really annoying when I provide help without getting the deserved acknowledgement, sometimes not even a comment.

Comment: @RHertel Thanks for the comment and the vote.  At times, it is annoying, but not all users are like that.  Just contribute to the SO thinking that you are helping somebody.  You will get rewarded with time.

Comment: @akrun I think you're right. Moreover I'm learning every day by helping others, that's already a reward.

Comment: Answer accepted not enough time had passed for me to accept it and I had left my computer.

Comment: @costebk08 Thanks, I thought that it was within that grace period.

Comment: A thumbs up on the question would also be much appreciated, but no problem thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: @costebk08 Thanks, have a great weekend to you as well!